# How to split columns into rows in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

My sample query returns the below data. I want to split the column data to rows.

I do not want to use `UNION ALL` as my query is very complex. Is there any other way to accomplish this? I am using DB2.

```
Current:
SKU_NBR   STR_NBR   ADDL_ORD_QTY    TRGT_OH_QTY   BUMP_INCR_QTY
301701     1902        60                40           20
346989     1902        60                             20

Expected:            
SKU_NBR     STR_NBR    Demand    
301701      1902        60   
301701      1902        40   
301701      1902        20   
346989      1902        60   
346989      1902       null  
346989      1902        20
```

Comment: Please share the query you tried

Comment: We would actually have to see the query.

Comment: select sku_nbr,str_nbr,addl_ord_qty,trgt_oh_qty,bump_incr_qty from qa1mm.dmnd where cor_pgm_id = 59 and pre_bld_id = 200 with ur;                                                                                                          This query gives me the 2 rows as shown in currect section above which I need to split into columns as shown above in expected section.

Comment: [Unpivot?](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en) which I think MicahelTiefenbacher already has shown..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `cross join`:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.SKU_NBR, t.STR_NBR,
       (case when n.n = 1 then ADDL_ORD_QTY
             when n.n = 2 then TRGT_OH_QTY
             when n.n = 3 then BUMP_INCR_QTY
        end) as demand
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 2 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 3 from sysibm.sysdummy1
     ) n;
```

Comment: @Gordon..I do not want to use union all, as my query is very complex so will be tough to maintain. What I have posted is a sample query. Is there any other option other than union all?

Comment: @Aish: You are not the union all on your table, the union all is used here to create a temp table that contains one column and 3 rows. The values are 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: @Aish . . . You can do it with a `(values (1), (2), (3)) as n(n)`, if you like.

Answer (score 3):

In my eyes it could be useful to see the source of the value as well - if not you can skip the column "type". Here is a possible solution using tp as table name:

```
select sku_nbr,str_nbr, type, demand
  from tp , 
       lateral(values ('ADDL_ORD_QTY', tp.ADDL_ORD_QTY), 
                      ('TRGT_OH_QTY', tp.TRGT_OH_QTY),
                      ('BUMP_INCR_QTY', tp.BUMP_INCR_QTY)) 
        as q(type, demand);
```